# How to allow file upload only for specific IP addresses of a php website

Tags: php, apache

Someone contacted me after their Linux, Apache2, MySQL, PHP website experienced a phishing attack.  I logged onto their server, added a firewall, deleted all phishing files, and I set `file_uploads = Off` in the `/etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini` file.

The website has a lot of pages that allow you to upload files.  Is there a way for me to allow users from just one or two specific IP addresses to still use these pages to upload content?  I read that I can't use `if(<valid ip address>) ini_set('file_uploads', 'On');` in the latest versions of PHP. Are there other approaches for me to consider?

---

**Background**

From what I can tell, the reason their site got attacked was because they have a lot of HTML forms that allow you to upload attachments.  There is no form validation or content sanitization at all. This explains why I saw files like `danger.zip` and `unzip.php` on the server, where by the `danger.zip` contains a bunch of viruses and phishing material and `unzip.php` is a webpage that performs the operation `unzip(danger.zip);`.

Comment: *"There is no form validation or content sanitization at all."* - That would be the problem then.  If the server-side code is accepting and handling any and all requests from clients, then anybody on the internet can send any request they want.  It's in that logic which handles the requests that you would authorize the request.  In this case that authorization would be to check the client's IP and conditionally handle the request or respond with an error.

Comment: Is there anything I can do at the apache level, .htaccess or something else?  I'm trying to avoid working with the code of this legacy project that was written almost 10 years ago

Comment: Possibly.  It's been ages since I've used an `.htaccess` file, but you may be able to (1) deny/blacklist all POST requests and (2) allow/whitelist POST requests from the given IP.

Comment: Uploading files does not constitute [a phishing attack](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/access-management/phishing-attack/#:~:text=%E2%80%9CPhishing%E2%80%9D%20refers%20to%20an%20attempt,or%20sell%20the%20stolen%20information.).

Comment: I cosnidered that, but there's a lot of people making POST requests for features like "Save my Cookie Settings, save my language settings, subscribe to newsletter" etc...

Comment: @John: Are those POST requests to the same URL?  You can probably specify the exact URLs/resources to apply the blacklist/whitelist rules to.  But the more custom you want the logic to be, the more that logic would be in code rather than configuration.

Comment: @kikosoftware - thansk for clarification .  The contents of the `danger.zip` are more php/html web pages asking peopel to type in their financial and personal details and other pages that execute the `mail()` function if triggered. Will tehse be considred phishing attacks?

Comment: No, not even those, but I understand what you mean. Anyway, the site shouldn't unpack uploaded ZIP files and execute the content, unless they come from a trusted source.

Comment: @David - OK, i'll investigate exactly which pages the content writers want to work with, and see if I have to devise on-off rules for each page

Comment: @John: *"Will tehse be considred phishing attacks?"* - Not really in this case.  If all the "attacker" is doing is uploading files to the server, that itself doesn't constitute phishing.  Phishing would be if the attacker is contacting users and pretending to be someone else (e.g. you) and asking for information.  If the server in question is serving these files to the user, then the attacker is tricking the server (you), not the user.  The lesson there is that the server shouldn't be allowing unauthorized users to update the code/contents of the server.

Comment: @John It would be more accurate to stay an attacker is exploiting a [unrestricted file upload](https://owasp.org/www-community/vulnerabilities/Unrestricted_File_Upload) vulnerability on your site to host a phishing site. The actual "phishing attack" would be where the attacker attempts to direct traffic to their malicious pages.

Comment: @user229044 - yup, that's accurate description of what happened!

Comment: @David - yeah the website was written by junior developers paid pennies per hour, and they didn't care.  So yup...that's why the website is what it is.

Comment: Well, now you (or they) know the price for paying pennies per hour. Do yourself a favor and fix the root cause - don't just apply band-aid. You now know _one_ vulnerability that the original developers have deployed. You don't know how many others there are, but the odds are high that there are more.

Comment: @OlafKock - everyone including the business owner don't want to fix the problem.  They want to remake the website with WordPress, Wix or similar.  And that's why I want to avoid deep dive into the code with one off rule exceptions here and there ..it's a messy rabbit hole.  Just hoping there is some global way to enable upload for just one IP address.  As a stop gap measure until we can delete this whole site.

Comment: You cannot reasonably accomplish what you're asking via simple global config in either PHP or Apache. Disallowing POST for all but a subset of IPs,, if such a thing is possible in this context, will break all manner of forms XHR. Filtering POST requests by content is a whole other ball of wax. You either have to locate and fix _all_ of the form handlers, or simply accelerate the replacement of the app.

Comment: But you also need to make the business understand that they can't just have WordPress installed once and then never update or otherwise maintain it at all. They might as well paint a big target on their website. _All_ apps need maintenance, and will effectively _rot_ as new vulnerabilities are discovered and exploited, and WordPress is the world's biggest magnet for attacks because of how widespread and generally poorly maintained it is.

Comment: What if I set up a new apache virtual host file that uses a different server name, but the website is served from the same source code as the "production" site.  Then the content person needs to update the host file of his own laptop to point to this new server name.  Maybe I can do something with this new virtual host file to enable file upload and restrict to just one IP address

Comment: And only me and the content writer would be aware of the fqdn of this servername.  And we a2dissite whenever we know we dont anticipate any content updates to the website?

Comment: Added my solution to the answers with the vhost approach

Comment: Anything **not** working with the given approach?  Also, why are the uploaded files executed anywhere on the server? The sole purpose for uploaded files should be that anybody can download them again, not that PHP runs them. This is what you should fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is my current solution.  I'm not going to press Accept on my own answer until enough people tell me ways to improve it. Or maybe someone can give a better answer.

Assume the following:

- `1.1.1.1` is the IP address of a Content Admin who wants to work with the CMS on the website
- `2.2.2.2` is the IP address of the server hosting the website and the CMS.
- `https://my-application.com` is the website the public sees.  No one can upload files because `file_uploads = Off` in the `/etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini` file.  This website is served out of the directory `/var/www/my-application` on the server with IP `2.2.2.2`.
- `https://supersecretwebsite.com` is a url that a developer and the Content Admin has agreed upon to keep as a secret url that no one should know about.

**Step 1** - On the server `2.2.2.2`, I create a file called `/etc/apache2/sites-available/supersecretwebsite.com.conf` with the following contents:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName supersecretwebsite.com
    # The production website is also hosted out of this DocumentRoot
    DocumentRoot /var/www/my-application

    # ... other options ...

    # allow file upload just for this vhost
    php_admin_value file_uploads 1
    <Location />
       Order deny,allow
       Deny from all
       # only the content admin's IP address can visit this website
       Allow from 1.1.1.1
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I run the command `a2ensite supersecretwebsite.com.conf && systemctl restart apache2`.

**Step 2** - The Content Admin most go to his Windows Laptop and open up the file `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and add the entry `2.2.2.2 supersecretwebsite.com`.

**Step 3** - Content Admin person can uplaod files while visiting `https://supersecretwebsite.com` but not when visiting `https://my-application.com`

Comment: Security through obscurity sounds strange. Also, this needs changes if the admin uses a new IP (from any mobile hotspot, from his second home, during vacation, when the router assigns a new one)

Comment: That's correct. A system admin must explicitly turn this on when requested by the content admin! I have a cron tab that will run a2dissite && rm -f suoerscretsite.conf every 5 minutes since the last modified time of the `supersecretwebsite.conf`

Answer (score 0):

I would implement an `IP address` check at a centralized location in the application, such as the `index.php` file which routes all web traffic. Since all requests are routed through `index.php`, you need to determine which requests are for file uploads.

```
$allowedUploadIps = ['123.456.789.000', '987.654.321.000'];

// Write a function to check if the current request is a file upload request
function isFileUploadRequest() {
    // then lets implement the logic to determine if the current request is for file uploads
    // This involves checking the request URI, parameters, etc.
    return strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/path-to-upload') !== false;
}

// check the check for file uploads
if (isFileUploadRequest() && !in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $allowedUploadIps)) {
    // IF IP is not allowed, terminate the request
    header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
    exit('File uploads are not allowed from your IP address.');
}

// Add your index.php logic after this code
```

Comment: All web traffic is routed to index.php.  then it's all custom home brewed framework that renders which ever controller or other PHP files depending on server request Uri and other factors, which doesn't follow any standards because it's been worked in by about 17 different developers over the past 10 years or so.  I can't make sense of things without spending more time which the business does not authorize me to do

Comment: You can implement an IP address check at a centralized location in the application, such as the index.php file which routes all web traffic. Since all requests are routed through index.php, you need to determine which requests are for file uploads. This can be based on the request URI, parameters, or other factors that distinguish file upload requests from others. Implement an IP check early in the index.php file, but only for requests that are identified as file upload requests. Validate the client's IP address against a list of allowed IPs, I updated the code